# How to change background color shape adapter android?

Tags: java, android

i am new android devloper There should a design model in these.The background shape color should be like this.[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wGfw.png) If you know how to change the coding given below let the konw how to change background shape  color below adapter coding change adapter background color layout

```
  `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="134dp"
   android:layout_height="205dp"
  android:orientation="vertical">
    
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#f6f6f6"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="false"
    android:layout_margin="7dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout
    android:id="@+id/lyt_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:mrl_rippleAlpha="0.2"
    app:mrl_rippleColor="@color/colorRipple"
    app:mrl_rippleHover="true"
    app:mrl_rippleOverlay="true">
  
       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/lyt_row_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical">
           <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,1:1"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                   <com.makeramen.roundedimageview.RoundedImageView
                        android:id="@+id/recipe_image"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail"
                        app:riv_corner_radius="8dp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/thumbnail_video"
                        android:layout_width="68dp"
                        android:layout_height="68dp"
                        android:alpha="0.8"
                        android:src="@drawable/ic_thumbnail_video"
                        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                        android:visibility="gone" />
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lytDiscount"
                        android:layout_width="70dp"
                        android:layout_height="30dp"
                        >

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="170dp"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_offer" />


                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/showDiscount"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:text="- 50%"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/_10ssp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                     </RelativeLayout>
                  </RelativeLayout>
              </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/lyt_title_row"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:text="25002"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Small"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/discountprice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="20023"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"

                    android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:paddingEnd="@dimen/dimen_5dp"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/_12sdp" />

            </LinearLayout>
           <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/lyt_title_row"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"

                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/recipe_title"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="1"
                            android:text="Title"
                            android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_title_size" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </RelativeLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_4sdp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/lyt_title_row"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/category_name"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:text="Category"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_sub_title_size" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lyt_comment"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="14dp"
                            android:layout_height="14dp"
                            android:src="@drawable/ic_comment"
                            app:tint="@color/colorGreyDark" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/comment"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_sub_title_size" />

                     </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

              </RelativeLayout>

          </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

       </com.balysv.materialripple.MaterialRippleLayout>

      </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

     </LinearLayout>`
```

How to change background color shape adapter android

Answer (score 0):

You can use color resources, specified usually inside res/values/colors.xml.

```
<color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

and in the XML layout definition you can add

```
android:background="@color/red"
```

to any view within the layout.

Once defined, the color can used anywhere else too.

Comment: bro how to change total adapter change

Comment: this image only 1/2 adapter ful fill how to change 1/2 adapter color https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wGfw.png

Comment: hi need same adapter https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wGfw.png